# Unittesting and mocking nodeJS net/Socket events

Tags: unit-testing, node.js, mocking, tdd, mocha.js

I'm TDD'ing a script that connects to a Socket from the `net` module.

For testing I use mocha and for mocking sinonjs

Now I'm really having problem mocking/faking the data-emitting of the Socket.

e.g.: I want to test this code:

```
socket.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
}
```

How can I fake an emit of 'data'?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to expose the `socket` variable to the test somehow. I'd need to see more of your code to recommend the best way to do that.

And then in your test, you can call `socket.emit()`.